# How can i remove error from my flutter project?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, project

[image]

How to remove error that I have in my project, although the app work fine with me without any problem

Comment: This is not an error but a bug in AS. You can restart your IDE and it will be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, this is just showing as error because you are working on a Flutter project. Flutter will never understand `build.gradle` file. That is why showing as error.

Open your `andorid` folder as separate project then the error will be gone.

or

Open `build.grale` file on the top of the file there is an option `Open for Editing in Android Studio` if you click this option the `android` module will open in separate window. Now also the error will be gone.

or

`Tools -> Flutter -> Open Android Module in Android Studio`. Now also the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

It is fault in android studio you can't remove this error. Restart your android studio then it'll be gone